# What is the better way to add office 365 javascript api library to angular js project?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, office365, restangular

Officejs library can be used inside angular controller as following way by adding library reference  https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js  to index page

```
function sendRequest() {
   // Create a local variable that contains the mailbox.
   var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;

   mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(getItemRequest(mailbox.item.itemId), callback);
}

function callback(asyncResult)  {
   var result = asyncResult.value;
   var context = asyncResult.context;

   // Process the returned response here.
}
```

is there any better way to handle these kind of libraries inside angular js project ?

Comment: Isn't this library only available (or at least made) for outlook add-in ? see: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman generater is there. it has option to create angular project
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-office